# requirement for monthly uptime and system performance

Tags: central-processing-unit, uptime, display

Management wants uptime and system performance data monthly (CPU) for our systems which consist of a mixture of linux/unix/windows machines.  Anything out there that might provide this information?

thanks

PS: what I am looking for is a simple monthly uptime/downtime calculation.  In terms of performance, maybe only just the average CPU use over the month just a single number perhaps, maybe average disk use over the month.  Not a monitoring system really, just something to record this easily over the broad range of systems we have.  Something very simple but easy and fast to implement without very much human overhead.

Comment: Can you give us more information on what you are looking to monitor/track? "system performance data" is a **HUGE** range of metrics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) best monitoring system to UNIX and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[Zabbix](http://zabbix.com) is an option.
[Nagios](http://nagios.org) (with some scripts to keep track of the data) is an option.
[Cacti](http://cacti.net) is an option.
[InterMapper](http://www.intermapper.com) (with InterMapper DataCenter for storing the data) is an option.

There are lots of other options too (ask Google) - which one you select depends on what you need to monitor/track.

Comment: I mostly use opennms.  They're all good options.

Comment: If all you're looking for is simple uptime/downtime all of these except Cacti are good choices (Cacti doesn't really have an "Availability" graph you can look at -- it's more "gaps mean it was down").

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, [`Uptime.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243) from the (old) Resource Kit tools will give nice useful numbers; check the various options.  It's a cli tool, so you'll need to graph the numbers manually.

I feel that in these days of commodity 16-core boxes, watching CPU is mostly pointless. (Unless you know you've got a calculation-bound legacy app.)   It's Teraflops of NOOPS.   Try to negotiate w/ management for a metric that embodies the performance the business really cares about - Page load times, Batch processing windows, what-have-you.